# ASP.NET MVC2 Dictionary Not Updating With Dynamic Index

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a search engine that scores database items parametrically.  Because of this, I have setup a scoring class that allows the controller to manage and return scores of specific items.  For example, say I am scoring computers.  If someone selects a specific amount of RAM in the search form, I want a match to score higher than say a near-match.

The class allows the addition of scores based on the ID of a database item as an index:

```
public class ScoringMechanism {
    // Dictionary that holds scores
    private Dictionary<int, int> _scores;

    public ScoringMechanism() {
        this._scores = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    public AddOrUpdate(int id, int score) {
        if (_scores.ContainsKey(id)) {
            _scores[id] += score;
        } else {
            _scores.Add(id, score);
        }
    }
}
```

Within the controller, I check for a match like so:

```
var computers = from computer in _context.Computers select computers;

foreach (Computer computer in computers) {
    if (computer.GBAmt == Request.Querystring["GB"]) {
       scores.AddOrUpdate(computer.ID, 15);
    }
}
```

What I am noticing in my code I can not figure out: when updating the score dynamically through the computer.ID variable, the score does not update.  However, when I explicitly state an id, it does update.

In essence,

```
scores.AddOrUpdate(15, 25);
```

works.

Comment: are you sure that `computer.ID` is not 0? In general, you could probably step through that code in the debugger and see what values are being passed around.

Comment: Yes, I am able to pull out a record of all the items in the database.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that there is one instance where it does work.  One of the problems though, is that I can't figure out why in that particular region it works while it doesn't even when I put no conditions.